# How do I change the Unity launcher color?

Tags: unity, launcher

I'm trying to change the panel and launcher color from gray to green or blue. I've tried myunity ccsm and the stock settings. But everytime I change the color it doesn't stick it reverts after I close the program used.

Answer (score 4):

I just installed Unsettings and it's excellent, handles the launcher and panel colour, opacity etc. It does a lot of other stuff too. There's a short piece about it here:

http://www.noobslab.com/2012/04/install-unsettings-tweak-tool-on-ubuntu.html

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug and is already reported and confirmed.

All you can do is wait till that's fixed. :(

I can't change my dash and launcher color, too,  let's hope that gets fixed asap. ^ ^

https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/975350

Answer (score 1):

For Launcher, you can try with MyUnity:

```
sudo apt-get install myunity
```

For panel, I'm afraid there is an only way to change the color of the panel, but you probably have to edit the theme files manually.

For example, to change the panel's color to black for the "Ambiance" theme, you have to find and edit the     `/usr/shared/themes/Ambience/gtk-2.0/apps/gnome-panel.rs` 
file. Replace the lines at the beginning, in the "panel" style from:

```
bg_pixmap[NORMAL] = "img/panel.png"
bg[NORMAL] = "#4b4a46"
```

to

```
bg[NORMAL] = "#000000"
```

But the changes might get lost if the theme gets updated.

Comment: Thanks for your response but I've already tried myunity and it reverts after closing the program and I couldn't find the gnome-panel.rs file you mention

Comment: Next question when's precise coming out of beta ;-)